# Help with product bundles where the bundles are mutiples of the same product

Tags: bundle, sku, group

I have no idea if this is actually possible but I'll ask anyway.

I have 5 x products with different SKUs
eg butX01,butX02,butX03,butX04,butX05

Each product costs 0.50

But what I want to do is sell multiple quantities and have different prices for that.

Eg 5x butX01 costs 1.90 etc.

I could have mutiple skus with different quantites, but it would be easier to just have the base sku with quantity.

Ie I want a sku which defines quantity of a different sku.

EG butX10 = 5 x butX01 etc.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the Grouped Product?

With a Grouped Product you can define severel simple Products with a defined qty to be sold as grouped.

If you raise the amount of the Grouped Product the amount of Items will be also risen to a certain amount

For example

but10 = 5x but01

Buying but10 twice will add 10 x but01 displayed as 2x but10 to your cart.

Comment: I've had a play and...... almost there but not quite.

The issue is now that the grouped products cant be used in configureables. However, I can probably explain a little better than I did the first time.

What I want is to stock one item but offer a drop down for quantity.

eg base item butX01 = 1 button

Comment: the easiest way woulf be to add a select instead of text input on products detail and cart page.
Or add a text notice like "the qty you select bundles with 5 items" or something. Sorry, my english is not the best.